# Dutch national flag sort

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to program a quicksort-ish algorithm using the [Dutch national flag algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem). I've tried everything I can to make this work and I'm getting really frustrated. Can you take a look and help me find the bugs?

```
import random

a = []
for i in range(100):
    a.append(random.randint(1, 100))

print(a)
def partion(array, left, right, lPiv, rPiv):
        high = len(array) -1
        p = left
        i = left
        while i < high:
                if array[i] < lPiv and array[i] < rPiv:
                        array[i],array[p]=array[p],array[i]
                        p = p+1
                        i = i+1
                elif array[i] > lPiv and array[i] > rPiv:
                        array[i],array[high]=array[high],array[i]
                        high = high-1
                else:
                        i = i+1

        return [p, high]

def piv(array, left, right):
    aMin = array[left]
    aMax = array[left]

    for i in array:
      if i < aMin:
          aMin = i
      if i > aMax:
          aMax = i
    return [aMin + ((aMax - aMin) /3), aMin + ((aMax-aMin)/3)*2]


def sort(array, left, right, depth):
    apiv = piv(array, left, right)
    part = partion(array, left, right, apiv[0], apiv[1])
    if right-left >= 3:
        piv1 = piv(array, left, part[0])
        part1 = partion(array, left, part[0], piv1[0], piv1[1])
        sort(array, left, part1[0], depth+1)


        piv2 = piv(array, part[0], part[1])
        part2 = partion(array, part[0], part[1], piv2[0], piv2[1])
        sort(array, part[0], part[1])

        piv3 = piv(array, part[1], right)
        part3 = partion(array, part[1], right, piv3[0], piv3[1] )
        sort(array, part[1], right)

    elif right-left < 3:
        if array[right] < array[left]:
            array[right],array[left] = array[left], array[right]
        else:
            return


sort(a, 0, len(a), 1)
print(a)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: It's an endless loop

...
 File "I:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/sort.py", line 49, in sort
    sort(array, left, part1[0], depth+1)
  File "I:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/sort.py", line 49, in sort
    sort(array, left, part1[0], depth+1)
  File "I:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/sort.py", line 49, in sort
    sort(array, left, part1[0], depth+1)
  File "I:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/sort.py", line 40, in sort
    print(array)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: Infinite recursion usually means there's a problem either what you're recursing on or a problem with your base case check.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to write Java in Python :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few bugs in your codes

1. sort() takes 4 parameters, so sort(array, part[0], part[1]) fails. btw depth is not necessary.
2. `if array[right] < array[left]:` and `sort(a, 0, len(a), 1)` .
   Right is out of array's index range when it is the length of the array.
3. piv should deal with the partion not the whole array
4. if numbers in the partion are all same, `aMin + ((aMax - aMin) /3)` and `aMin + ((aMax-aMin)/3)*2` are the same index
5. since partition only deals with a partion not thw whole array, `high = len(array) -1` should be `high = right -1`
6. `part1 = partion(array, left, part[0], piv1[0], piv1[1])` is wrong. Sort() partitions the array at it's beginning, don't partition twice in the same recursion. just call sort(array,...).
7. your partition partitionalgorithm is wrong and I can't find a simple fix for it

---

Here's my implementation.

```
import random
from itertools import islice
a = []
for i in range(100):
    a.append(random.randint(1, 100))

def partition(array, left, right, lPiv, rPiv):
        q = right -1
        p = left
        r = left
        while p<=q:
            if array[p]<=lPiv:
                array[p], array[r] = array[r], array[p]
                p = p+1
                r = r+1
            elif lPiv<array[p]<=rPiv:
                p = p+1
            else:
                array[p], array[q] = array[q], array[p]
                q=q-1

        return (p, q+1)

def piv(array, left, right):
    aMin = min(islice(a,left,right))
    aMax = max(islice(a,left,right))
    return (aMin + ((aMax - aMin) /3.0), aMin + ((aMax-aMin)/3.0)*2)


def sort(array, left, right):
    if right-left >= 3:
        piv_left, piv_right = piv(array, left, right)
        if piv_left == piv_right:
            return
        pt_left, pt_right = partition(array, left, right, piv_left, piv_right)
        sort(array, left, pt_left)
        sort(array, pt_left, pt_right)
        sort(array, pt_right, right)
    elif right-left <3:
        if left<right and array[right-1] < array[left]:
            array[right-1],array[left] = array[left], array[right-1]


sort(a, 0, len(a))
print a

#test
assert( a==sorted(a) )
```

Answer (score 0):

piv seems to return tha same value always, does it? Maybe the for loop should be over array[left:right] instead over the whole array?